# PHP , Using SSE, Can't echo the data back to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

So I am using SSE EventListener, Where this Script will Listen to OnMessage Event that happens at respond.php

```
 if(typeof(EventSource !== "undefined")){
var source = new EventSource('respond.php');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

console.log(e.data);
}, false);}
else{
console.log("Sorry SSE is not working");
}
```

Respond.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Body'])){
$myfile = fopen("data.txt","w");
    $input = $_POST['Body'];
    fwrite($myfile,"$input");
    fclose($myfile);
    echo "data: $input\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

  }
```

This respond.php code basically say when this php gets an POST variable ready then write it to a data.txt then echo the data. I can see whenever I post an $_POST['Body'. data.txt gets update, So that means inside of the IF is getting executed BUT, the echo part just won't firing? The JAVASCRIPT onMessageListener is just not picking it up?(I did try to create an ELSE Part and echo something, and the Listener pick that up.)So I really don't know what is Happening here. Can someone please help?

Comment: how are you POSTing data to the SSE script?

Comment: lets say an message comes in and post it on PHP, then i want PHP to push that message body to JS. I don't want to use websocket .

Comment: `Server Sent Events` - SSE - are not intended, nor able, to receive data via POST but it is a simple task to pass any form data to the sse script using a standard GET request. Once the SSE connection has been opened then traffic only flows from the server ( sse script ) to the client. If the `message` to which you refer is stored in the database then you can send that back easily by running a sql query and processing the results. For bi-directional communication then WebSockets or Ajax long-polling are your best options.

Comment: @RamRaider That is an answer (the answer), not a comment :-)